# 'Consume' as a noun

Tags: word-choice

In 'Meteorites and Their Parent Planets', H. Y. McSween writes:

> Chondrites are not well-blended consumes of ingredients, but instead are lumpy, heterogeneous aggregates of different components.

I am not familiar with this use of 'consume' as a noun and it is not listed in dictionaries, e.g. the O.E.D. Is this usage a mistake? What word might have been meant?

[Meteorites and Their Parent Planets, 2ed, H. Y. McSween, CUP, 1999](https://books.google.com/books?id=BtNJoP5HlU8C&q=Chondrites+are+not+well-blended+consumes+of+ingredients%2C+but+instead+are+lumpy%2C+heterogeneous+aggregates+of+different+components#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Comment: It sounds as if it's either a typo (maybe *consumers*) or a technical usage. If the latter,it may be better to ask this question in [astronomy.se].

Comment: Or maybe *consommés* (soups).

Comment: Just a thought, but "consommé" is a French word, adopted into English, meaning a smooth, clear soup, as opposed to a lumpy soup or broth. The Spanish spelling is "consumé", both having plurals ending in "s". "Consumes" may be a misprint or typo, possibly - I certainly can't find a dictionary definition of "consumes" that satisfies the obvious meaning. @Mick - I really should learn to type faster!

Comment: @Spratty Sometimes, less is more. ;-)

Comment: The mistyped *consommé* or *consumé* sort of makes sense in context, but meteorites are hard and not really soup-like, so it's not a great analogy.  Either way, it's incorrect: either a typo or just plain wrong.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Or a technical term. It is from a scientific paper.

Comment: @Mick it's possible I suppose, but my money's on "error"

Comment: It's not a scientific paper, but a book intended for a wide audience.

Comment: @Mick The book has a glossary which doesn't include 'consume' or 'consumes', though it does contain fairly basic entries like 'crater', so technical term seems unlikely, also the section heading is 'Chondrite Recipes' making a food analogy more understandable.

Comment: @MaxWilliams I'd like to know what the author actually intended. If he meant *soup*, he should have used *soup*. It's rather intriguing, since no obvious English word (except for consumer) comes to mind. Maybe someone will think of one.

Comment: @Mick I wouldn't like to introduce any "no metaphors!" or "no foreign words!" rules for writers, that sounds a bit draconian!

Comment: @Mick he's a planetary geoscientist, not a cookery writer, he perhaps didn't know people would be so exacting about a loose metaphor. Harry Y McSween's email address is readily findable online should anyone feel up to asking the man himself...

Comment: @Spratty: The omission of the accent on the é does have precedents. E.g. compare the AmE "coupe" (coop) and the original French "coupé" (coo-pay).

Comment: This is just a spelling mistake.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's asking about a spelling mistake.

Answer (score -1):

After reading the text various times, I think the word that fits better is: combination.

1- It is similar to "consumes" (which is obviously out of place).

2- It preserves the idea in the sentence and the paragraph too.

Btw, nice catch. It requires a close reading to notice errors of this kind.